# Unable to access variables in different classes

Tags: java

```
package penny_pinch_v2;

public class Prizes {

    public static String[] prizes = { "Puzzle", "Poster", "Ball", "Game", "Doll" };

}

===========Separate Class File============

package penny_pinch_v2;

public class RunPennyPinch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(prizes[1]);

        }
}
```

I'm trying to access the array 'prizes' in a different class, but it keeps saying that 'prizes' cannot be resolved.  If you could tell me how to fix this that would be great.

Comment: What if there are few classes with `prizes` array? How should compiler or JVM know which one you want to access? How do you think this problem could be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix the variable with the class name as the variable is not within the **RunPennyPinch** class.

```
System.out.print(Prizes.prizes[1]);
```

You may also have to import the **Prizes** class, depending on your set-up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referencing a static field in another class you will need to use the name of that class to reference the field, so basically you need to change your main to this:

```
public class RunPennyPinch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Prizes.prizes[1]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a namespacing issue.  Let's pretend you *could* do what you're trying to do.  What if you make another class called `Prizes2` and put another variable in it, also named `prizes`?  How does `RunPennyPinch` know which `prizes` variable it should be using?

Perhaps you could solve this problem by saying, "only one `prizes` variable is allowed to exist in any program at one time".  If this were a real limitation, you would quickly run out of meaningful names to give to variables.

The solution that Java came up with is namespacing: To give a variable a context it lives in.  Two variables can have the same name, but as long as they have a different context, they won't *clash*.  The price you pay is you have to tell the program which context you want to use when you're referring to a variable.

Here's how to fix the problem:

```
package penny_pinch_v2;

public class Prizes {

    public static String[] prizes = { "Puzzle", "Poster", "Ball", "Game", "Doll" };

}

//===========Separate Class File============

package penny_pinch_v2;

public class RunPennyPinch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(Prizes.prizes[1]);

        }
}
```

There's something else you should know: If you don't explicitly state a context, it defaults to using `this` as the context.  As an unrelated example, these two methods do the same thing and both work:

```
package foo;

public class Bar {

    public String baz = "Puzzle";

    public void impliedThis() {
        System.out.println(baz);
    }

    public void explicitThis() {
        System.out.println(this.baz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable itself doesn't exist in that context.  It's a static member of another class.  So you need a reference to that class:

```
System.out.print(Prizes.prizes[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of static is that you dont have to create an object to access that variable. You just have to call that variable by Classname.variablename   (Classname is the name of class in which that variable was present)

```
 System.out.print(Prizes.prizes[1]);
```